# ArangoDB array query for an array

Tags: arangodb, aql

I am trying to write an update command in arangodb to insert an single "key":"value" attribute in document having nested array.

```
{
  "OuterBlock": {
    "InnerBlock": {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": {
        "key21": "value21"
      },
      "key3": {
        "key31": "value31"
      },
      "key4": [
        {
          "key41": "value1",
          "key42": {
            "key421": "value421"
          },
          "key43": [
            {
              "key431": "value431",
              "key432": {
                "key4321": "value4321"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "key44": "value44",
          "key45": {
            "key451": "key451"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I need to add one more key:value pair under key432 (example: "key4322":"value4322"). I tried with select query first and tried to add this attribute using MERGE command.

```
FOR t IN test 
FILTER t._key=="Test"
Collect a = t.OuterBlock.InnerBlock.key4[0].key43[0].key432 into aitems
LET newa = (MERGE(a , {"key4322": "value4322"}))
RETURN newa
```

It returned result as below

```
[
  {
    "key4321": "value4321",
    "key4322": "value4322"
  }
]
```

so i tried merging this result with first block "key43" using below query

```
FOR t IN test
FILTER t._key=="Test"
collect a = t.OuterBlock.InnerBlock.key4[0].key43[0]  into aitems
LET newa = (MERGE(a , {key432: 
(
FOR t IN test 
FILTER t._key=="Test"
Collect b = t.OuterBlock.InnerBlock.key4[0].key43[0].key432 into bitems
LET newb = (MERGE(b , {"key4322": "value4322"}))
Return newb
)
}))
RETURN newa
```

And the output is giving me an additional array block [] in key432 which is not there in the original data. hence it is changing the format of the document. How can i remove this array block.
Please suggest.

```
[
  {
    "key431": "value431",
    "key432": **[**
      {
        "key4321": "value4321",
        "key4322": "value4322"
      }
    **]**
  }
]
```

Comment: Please help as i'm struggling with this array for few days. tried with PUSH but no luck :( since retrieve query is not working, i am no where near update statement for this requirment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace array elements and merge objects step by step because variables in AQL are immutable. It would be easier to extend the nested object on the client-side and then replace the whole document on the server-side. It is possible in AQL, nonetheless:

```js
FOR t IN test
  FILTER t._key == "test"
  LET key432 = MERGE(
    t.OuterBlock.InnerBlock.key4[0].key43[0].key432,
    { key4322: "value4322" }
  )
  LET key43 = REPLACE_NTH(
    t.OuterBlock.InnerBlock.key4[0].key43, 0,
    MERGE(t.OuterBlock.InnerBlock.key4[0].key43[0], { key432 })
  )
  LET key4 = REPLACE_NTH(t.OuterBlock.InnerBlock.key4, 0,
    MERGE(t.OuterBlock.InnerBlock.key4[0], { key43 })
  )
  RETURN MERGE_RECURSIVE(t, { OuterBlock: { InnerBlock: { key4 } } })
```

Result:

```json
[
  {
    "OuterBlock": {
      "InnerBlock": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": {
          "key21": "value21"
        },
        "key3": {
          "key31": "value31"
        },
        "key4": [
          {
            "key41": "value1",
            "key42": {
              "key421": "value421"
            },
            "key43": [
              {
                "key431": "value431",
                "key432": {
                  "key4321": "value4321",
                  "key4322": "value4322"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "key44": "value44",
            "key45": {
              "key451": "key451"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Regarding the extra array, keep in mind that subqueries always return an array just like the top-level query does.

```js
LET newa = (MERGE(a , {key432: 
(
FOR t IN test ... // subquery
)
```

To take just the first element returned by the subquery, you can do `FIRST( FOR ... )` or `( FOR ... )[0]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I will check this query. 
One doubt - can you explain this line little more - "It would be easier to extend the nested object on the client-side and then replace the whole document on the server-side."

Comment: AQL does not let you change variables in place, but you can do that in e.g. JavaScript like `doc.OuterBlock.InnerBlock.key4[0].key43[0].key432.key4322 = "value4322"`. So modifying the data structure becomes easier. Then you need to replace the original document with the modified one, e.g. in AQL with `REPLACE { ... } IN test`. You could implement this on the client-side with arangojs, but you could also write your own AQL function in JavaScript that returns the modified document: https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/extending.html

Comment: i cant use replace_nth as i'm using lower version of arango database

Comment: As it's the first element in both cases, you can use `UNSHIFT(SHIFT(t.OuterBlock.InnerBlock.key4[0].key43), MERGE(...))` and `UNSHIFT(SHIFT(t.OuterBlock.InnerBlock.key4), MERGE(...))` instead. A generic solution for any position would be `(FOR i IN 0..LENGTH(<array>)-1 RETURN i == <pos> ? <new-value> : <array>[i])`.

Comment: Note that `REPLACE_NTH()` was introduced in v3.7.0 and v3.6 support ends next month (end of August 2021).

Comment: Got it. Thanks a ton!. I was able to clear extra array and form the update statement as well.